# Unusual reshape of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contourf

I am trying to render geophysics section with **contourf** map in **matplotlib**.
I almost get desired result with only one exception, it renders from the bottom left corner.
[Rendered geophysics section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwWpg.png)

As it is section from surface, so 0 is a surface level, and 2000 is depth in nanoseconds. That means this contourf map needs to be rendered from top left corner.

```
CS = plt.contourf(x, y, amplitude, 25, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=127)
```

I think i understanding the problem. My data is readed from binary file, where every shot is a list of values from surface to deepest value in every given point. So my 2D array is like:

```
1st shot [[65, 29, 56, 98, 82, 14,...],
2nd shot  [24, 54, 48, 41, 74, 37,...],
3rd shot  [34, 12, 18, 44, 87, 64,...]]
N shot....
```

Is there a way to reshape it like:

```
[[65, 24, 34],
 [29, 54, 12],
 [56, 48, 18],
 [98, 41, 44],
 [82, 74, 87],
 [14, 37, 64]]
```

This way if y invert y values (to be negatives) i could get desired result - 0 in upper left corner.

I know how to do is in plain python, but is there an efficient way in **numpy**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data D is a numpy 2D array,

```
D = D.T
```

a simple transpose will achieve that.